# Sum up values in first column for all identical strings in the second column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Let's say I have the following 2 files with entries such as these (number, IP and User-agent):

```
30000 11.11.11.11 Dalvik/2.1.0 Linux
10000 22.22.22.22 GetintentCrawler getintent.com
 5000 33.33.33.33 Mozilla/5.0 X11; Linux i686 AppleWebKit/537.36 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
 3000 44.44.44.44 Mozilla/5.0 Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8 AppleWebKit/534.59.10 KHTML, like Gecko Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10
 1000 55.55.55.55 Dalvik/1.6.0 Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; Orange Yumo Build/OrangeYumo
```

and

```
 6000 44.44.44.44 Mozilla/5.0 Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8 AppleWebKit/534.59.10 KHTML, like Gecko Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10
 3000 33.33.33.33 Mozilla/5.0 X11; Linux i686 AppleWebKit/537.36 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
 2000 11.11.11.11 Dalvik/2.1.0 Linux
  600 55.55.55.55 Dalvik/1.6.0 Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; Orange Yumo Build/OrangeYumo
  500 22.22.22.22 GetintentCrawler getintent.com
```

I want to be able to sum up the first column for all identical IPs (the second column), while also keeping all the subsequent columns with the user-agent. Also, the final output should be sorted by first column.

So the result should basically look like this:

```
32000 11.11.11.11 Dalvik/2.1.0 Linux
10500 22.22.22.22 GetintentCrawler getintent.com
 9000 44.44.44.44 Mozilla/5.0 Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8 AppleWebKit/534.59.10 KHTML, like Gecko Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10
 8000 33.33.33.33 Mozilla/5.0 X11; Linux i686 AppleWebKit/537.36 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
 1600 55.55.55.55 Dalvik/1.6.0 Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; Orange Yumo Build/OrangeYumo
```

So far I came up with this, but I lose the whole user-agent string and I also feel that I'm overcomplicating things:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | awk '{arr[$2]+=$1;} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' | awk '{ print $2" "$1 }' | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `gnu-awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} {
   p=$1; $1=""; a[$0]+=p} END{for (i in a) print a[i] i}' file1 file2
```

`BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"}` is used to maintain order of keys in associative array.

**Output:**

```
32000 11.11.11.11 Dalvik/2.1.0 Linux
10500 22.22.22.22 GetintentCrawler getintent.com
8000 33.33.33.33 Mozilla/5.0 X11; Linux i686 AppleWebKit/537.36 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
9000 44.44.44.44 Mozilla/5.0 Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8 AppleWebKit/534.59.10 KHTML, like Gecko Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.10
1600 55.55.55.55 Dalvik/1.6.0 Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; Orange Yumo Build/OrangeYumo
```

Comment: Judging from the desired output and yours, you and the OP have different views about what is _the whole user-agent string_...

Comment: Thanks!
For me the sorting part doesn't work (I'm on CentOS 6, with gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64). But I can easily fix it with a pipe to sort -rn. So it's fine by me! I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: May I mention that your answer qualifies for the _This Week's Useless Use of `Cat` Award_, as you have TWO useless uses of `cat` in it? Upvoted nevertheless... ciao

Comment: LMAO @gboffi! Cut the guy some slack, it's an honest mistake :)

Comment: @Andy It's you that started the useless use stuff...! Just for the casual reader (sure you and Anubhava know it for the best): one good point of `awk` is that it keeps separate counters for the total number of records and the number of records in the current file but using `cat`, hence forcing `awk` to read form `stdin`, completely defeats this mechanism.  Of course this is not a problem with your problem and Anubhava's solution, but it's a thing that must be clear to every `awk` user. Ciao

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ghoti,  I've removed `cat` now (it was just inherited from question)